# In R, why order() works like this?

Tags: r

```
X <- matrix(c(10,9,
              1,4,
              9,1,
              5,10,
              3,10,
              3,6), ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)

y <-c("a","b","a",'c','c','b')

X_new <- matrix(c(6,4,
                  9,2,
                  7,2), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

knn<- function(train_x, train_y, test_x){
  train_x <- as.matrix(train_x)
  test_x <- as.matrix(test_x)
  
  d1 <- dim(train_x)
  n1 <- d1[1] 
  p2 <- d1[2] 
  
  d2 <- dim(test_x)
  n2 <- d2[1] 
  p2 <- d2[2]
  
  pred_y <- rep(0,n2)
  for (i in 1:n2) {
    X_temp = train_x - matrix(test_x[i,], nrow=nrow(train_x),ncol=ncol(train_x), byrow = TRUE)
    euc_dist =sqrt(rowSums(X_temp^2))
    print(euc_dist)
    print(order(euc_dist))
    pred_y[i] <- train_y[which.min(euc_dist)]
  }
  return (pred_y)
}

knn(X,y,X_new)
```

this prints like the below

[1] 6.403124 5.000000 4.242641 6.082763 6.708204 3.605551

[1] 6 3 2 4 1 5

[1]  7.071068  8.246211  1.000000  8.944272 10.000000  7.211103

[1] 3 1 6 2 4 5

[1] 7.615773 6.324555 2.236068 8.246211 8.944272 5.656854

[1] 3 6 2 1 4 5

[1] "b" "a" "a"

I think the first order() should print "5 3 2 4 6 1"

"6 3 2 4 1 5" isn't what I expected.
there's something I miss??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the order in which the values should appear to get an ordered vector. This is more easily shown than explained:

```
out <- c(6.403124, 5.000000, 4.242641, 6.082763, 6.708204, 3.605551)
order(out)
# [1] 6 3 2 4 1 5
```

So like you say, it looks odd, because you expect `c(2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 6)` (or `c(5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 1)` in ascending order). But one common way of using order is `x[order(x)]` to get the ordered vector, and if you do that, you get:

```
out[order(out)]
# [1] 3.605551 4.242641 5.000000 6.082763 6.403124 6.708204
```

or

```
out[order(out, decreasing = TRUE)]
# [1] 6.708204 6.403124 6.082763 5.000000 4.242641 3.605551
```

which is pretty useful.

If you want to know which place in the hierarchy the values are, you could go with `rank`:

```
rank(out)
# [1] 5 3 2 4 6 1
```

or

```
rank(desc(out))
# [1] 2 4 5 3 1 6
```

Comment: Ah I missed the meaning of order()'s return. thanks. I got it.